# Best way to get Context in clickable modifier

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-context

I have a piece of text that I want to call function X when clicked. I'm using the clickable modifier and calling function X in the onClick method to do this. However, function X uses Context.

To solve this problem, I'm using the approach outlined below:

```
@Composable
fun ClickableText() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    Text("Click me!", Modifier.clickable { functionX(context) })
}
```

My question is, is there anything wrong with this type of approach? It seems to be working, but storing a local reference to LocalContext.current seems a bit hacky. If the Context ever changes in the time between the UI composition and the onClick method call, I'd assume this could cause some issues. Is there a better way to get Context in a non-composable callback function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is totally correct way of using `LocalContext.current`. It cannot change between recomposition and `onClick`.

`Context` is getting created before the composable view: usually it's your activity, and if you're using Hilt it may be a context wrapper, but it's getting created once before [`setContent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/compose/package-summary#(androidx.activity.ComponentActivity).setContent(androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionContext,kotlin.Function0)), so if it'll change the whole compose view hierarchy will be rebuilt.

You shouldn't store it outside of the view, like in view models, but capturing it inside a composable is totally fine.